# How to add a ListViewItem in ListView control in asp.net code behind

Tags: asp.net, listview, code-behind, listviewitem

I have declared a listView control on an aspx page.

e.g. `<asp:Listview ID="ListView1" runat="server"><ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate></asp:Listview>`

I want to know that how i can add one or more ListViewItems in code behind.

***Please don't give a solution that uses DataSource and DataBind methods for the ListView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No other way of binding data to ListView except DataSourceId and SataSource
Check the [ListView control Reference from MSDN Here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.ASPX)

Comment: I think you  want change the layout after databinding, then try the Item_DataBound event for reference
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25393/Explicitly-binding-data-to-the-ListView-web-contro